# java ee MVC pattern, does model and view communicate directly with each other

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I'm currently learning java ee by following the book "java ee 7 the big picture".

In the book, the author had a picture to illustrate MVC pattern in java ee.

[image]

As you can see, in the figure, the model and the view are directly communicating with each other.

But my understand of MVC (I first learned MVC pattern from iOS development) is that model and view should NEVER communicate directly with each other. All the communication between model and view should be done through the controller (i.e. the controller act as the interpreter between model and view).

So is this diagram flawed? Or is it correct, and I need to re-adjust my understanding of MVC pattern the java ee way?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are in the good way. The view does not interact directly with the model. As I understand, I think the diagram is trying to explain that the model send the data to the view, but the view can't reach the model without controller help.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram doesn't seem that helpful. In javaEE the controller would accept the form filled out by the user, doing validation, then hand off the data to a service layer to do the update, then redirect to a controller that fetches the new updated object (the model) and adds it to the request as a request attribute, forwarding to a template that generates html. The view is some sort of template that knows to look for the model in the request attributes. So the model doesn't know to tell the view anything, typically as far as the view is concerned the model is a data container and nothing more.